# CakePHP memory usage deletion/flushing

Tags: cakephp, memory-management

is there a possibility to free the whole Memory used by CakePHP during `findAll()` method?
I try to seperate the huge select on my database in single parts but i cant find a way to delete the memory (get by `memory_get_usage`) after every part. 
I try to unset the `TableModel` after every Select, `clearCache`, `cacheMethods = false` and `public $cacheQueries = false` are all do nothing to reduce the memory usage by CakePHP's Selects on mysql - Database.
iam using CakePHP 2.4.*

I start at 3792752 Bytes of memory usage. And end up in 249679096 Bytes by selection about 90k of Data-Rows.

Please help me! I just farmed the internet hard trying to solve that memory leak stuff.
But i just dont find anything helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user2140111 how are you using Cake 2.4.* when the current release is 2.3.5? Are you using some unstable branch or what? 
Try to run your query with a SQL `EXPLAIN`directly over your database to see what's going on there. Also use SQL `limit` to "split it up" in parts and then check the memory usage.

238 MB is a lot of memory but I doubt it is just comming from the DB select - this is so privded that you do not store any blobs. Are you storing blobs?

There could be a lot of unused variables just sitting in your memory.

Comment: i just create an array by myself to make sure the error isnt located in the array. Cake Returns an array like that : array[i][tablename][fieldname] = value. i just imitate that and the amount of memory used is allmost the same. while($i <90000){array[$i]['table'name][fieldname]=value;$i++}. So think the problem is the array

Comment: i use the 2.3.5 Stable version now but nothings changed.

Answer (score 1):

That amount of memory in use is more pointing in the direction of some errors in your code.
Make sure debug is turned to 2 or 3 and check the code for errors. Try to run the sql query in PhPMyAdmin it might tell you something is wrong in the way you queury the Database.

Comment: My query: SELECT * WHERE tablename WHERE created_at >= "from_param" AND created _at <= "till_param". As simple as it can be. MyPHPAdmin just execute it in less then 1 second.

Comment: There is no debug setting == 3.

Comment: Yes, there is a debug option 3 in cakePHP, just read the manual, not sure why I got this down vote, because my answer is quite clear, That amount of memory usage is down to errors in coding! you need to check your code in cakephp, put at several places the debug($var); and even a die(); and check what goes on. in cakephp when using the standard stylesheet yo can see at bottom the mysql output, is it the same as in phpmyadmin, if not, are the relations in your model correct, [supposing you tested only the table involved in phpmyadmin!]

Comment: /**
 * CakePHP Debug Level:
 *
 * Production Mode:
 * 0: No error messages, errors, or warnings shown. Flash messages redirect.
 *
 * Development Mode:
 * 1: Errors and warnings shown, model caches refreshed, flash messages halted.
 * 2: As in 1, but also with full debug messages and SQL output.
 * 3: As in 2, but also with full controller dump. (NOTE: Not in CakePHP 1.3) 
 *
 * In production mode, flash messages redirect after a time interval.
 * In development mode, you need to click the flash message to continue.
 */

Comment: some debugging as this might help. echo $this->element('sql_dump');

//debug($enqData);
//die();

debug($this->User->validationErrors);

print_r($_SESSION);

Comment: When you check your models, be aware of this. The CakePHP recursive attribute can be set to the following integer values, with the following meanings:
Value   Meaning
-1      returns only the current model, and ignores all associations.
 0      returns the current model, plus its owner(s).
 1      returns the current model, its owner(s), plus their associated models.
 2      returns the current model, its owner(s), their associated models,
        and the associated models of any associations.

Comment: Up there i have imitate the array i get from the CakePHP-select. The memory usage is sadly allmost the same with 90k data-rows. So i think the problem is the huge array CakePHP creates.#

Comment: i have no associations set in there till now.

Comment: well i've checked the Query in PHPADMIN spend bit more the 24ms, in CakePHP with the $this->element('sql_dump') func it spend 126ms. Thats okay i think. So the database is still fast enought even if its executed directly or though CakePHP. So is it possible that the Array- Structure cause the trouble?

Comment: Check if you have correct file right to store in /app/tmp   and also check if you run this on a server hosted on the Internet [not a wampp] how your settings are with php.ini, memory allocted in php and so on. It might be worth to try it in a wampp situation to see if it works, then you know for sure your server related settings are playing up.

Comment: Yes it could be that Cake crates a huge array. Hey could you show us the query so that we're not just talking?

@Nick where are you reading this for the debug level 3?
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#cakephp-core-configuration
There is also nothing in `app/Config/core.php/`?

Comment: SELECT `LogRequest`.`id`, `LogRequest`.`ip`, `LogRequest`.`user_id`, `LogRequest`.`session_id`, `LogRequest`.`duration`, `LogRequest`.`duration_backend`, `LogRequest`.`request`, `LogRequest`.`response`, `LogRequest`.`parameter`, `LogRequest`.`err`, `LogRequest`.`created_at` FROM `bob_reporting_david`.`arc_log_requests` AS `LogRequest` WHERE `LogRequest`.`created_at` between '2011-10-18 16:15:00' AND '2012-10-18 16:30:00'

Comment: Well at least I have split the selection in parts. That solves my problem but it ain't give me an explanation why this huge amout of memory usage happens.